# Timeout context manager error using sanic and telepot same time

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, sanic

I'm trying to create a web app that communicates with Telegram. And trying to use `Sanic` web framework with `Telepot`. Both are `asyncio` based. Now I'm getting a very weird error.

This is my code:

```py
import datetime
import telepot.aio
from sanic import Sanic

app = Sanic(__name__, load_env=False)
app.config.LOGO = ''

@app.listener('before_server_start')
async def server_init(app, loop):
    app.bot = telepot.aio.Bot('anything', loop=loop)

    # here we fall
    await app.bot.sendMessage(
        "@test",
        "Wao! {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        debug=True
    )
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```py
[2018-01-18 22:41:43 +0200] [10996] [ERROR] Experienced exception while trying to serve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 646, in run
    serve(**server_settings)
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 588, in serve
    trigger_events(before_start, loop)
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 496, in trigger_events
    loop.run_until_complete(result)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1364, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/sanic-telepot.py", line 14, in server_init
    "Wao! {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 109, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telepot/aio/__init__.py", line 100, in sendMessage
    return await self._api_request('sendMessage', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 109, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telepot/aio/__init__.py", line 78, in _api_request
    return await api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 109, in __next__
    return self.gen.send(None)
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telepot/aio/api.py", line 139, in request
    async with fn(*args, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 690, in __aenter__
    self._resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 221, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/home/mk/Dev/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 712, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used '
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

`Telepot` inside uses `aiohttp` as dependency and for the HTTP calls. And the very similar code is working if I make very similar functionality with just `aiohttp.web`.

I'm not sure to what project this problem is related. Also, all other dependencies like `redis`, database connections that I connected the same approach are working perfectly.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I filled issue in the telepot repository and working on the fix https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/359